# Get access to "Office 365 Group" documents from Word "Open" dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, word

I know I can paste the link to the group files into the address bar and refresh the dialog view, eg https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/groupalias/Shared%Documents

I would like to add a link within the initial "Open file..." dialog, so my users could just click that link and be lead to the group docs:
[image]

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this in SPO yet.

The previous way to do this in on-prem installations was to utilize the Publish links to Office applications in the User Profile Service. You should be able to do this in SharePoint Online by going to your tenant administration, clicking User Profiles, and clicking Publish Links to Office Client Applications.

Add your url, and it should trickle down to Office Applications as a place to save files.